# Error trying to add JavaScript to Azure B2C Local Signup Page

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-ad-b2c

I have the following arbitrary JavaScript snippet on an HTML page stored in Azure Storage (using a screenshot to try to demonstrate, as far as I can see, that the syntax is correct):
[image]

The page loads, it is styled correctly and everything else you would expect, proving that it is configured correctly, CORS is set etc. But the JavaScript does not run. Instead I get this error:

```
unified:5 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '&'
at br (unified?local=signup&[omitted_for_brevity])
at at (unified?local=signup&[omitted_for_brevity])
at i.fn.init.append (unified?local=signup&[omitted_for_brevity])
at unified?local=signup&[omitted_for_brevity]
```

This is presumably being caused by this:
[image]

Extra script caused by some kind of parse or encoding error on the original script tag.

If I load the file from storage container directly, it loads and the JavaScript fires with no problems. This tells me the HTML file is fine, so either:

- how I am loading it does not play nicely with B2C
- I have not configured something on the B2C side to allow JavaScript
- Something else

I have configured everything that I can see on the User Flow:

- Enable *JavaScript enforcing page layout* is set to *On*
- Path to custom HTML is set
- CORS is configured for the custom HTML

Has anyone seen this problem before or can see what I may have done wrong in how this is configured?

Edit:
Am roughly following this guide:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/javascript-and-page-layout?pivots=b2c-user-flow

Answer (score 0):

It is definitely a parser error, the html & javascript is fine. You would need trace the error to find what function is parsing the code incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

After much head banging in to my desk, and a complete lack of help/clue from Microsoft support, the answer was quite simple - the inline function.

So instead of:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    alert('hello, world!');
});
```

I used

```
function onLoad() {
    alert('hello, world!');
}
onLoad();
```

And this worked fine (including not needing to be registered on DOMContentLoaded).